# How can I prevent bar labels from going outside the barplot boundaries/range?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to prevent the bar labels from going outside the plot's boundaries. I understand that I could simply use `plt.xlim([-14, 8])` to make the labels fit but that range does not work if an animal's score changed to a value lower than -14 or higher than 8.

Is there a way to make a "dynamic" range that will always fit the bar labels, no matter the score (even if the lowest score was, for example, -50 or -0.32, or the highest score was 50 or 0.32)?

```
import pandas as pd

score = [0.1, 0, -10.15, -2.04, 5.00, 2.45, 1.02]
index = ['snail', 'pig', 'elephant',
         'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': score}, index=index)

ax = df.plot.barh(y='score', legend=False)
ax.axvline(x=0, linestyle='-', linewidth=2.5, color = '#17191a')
ax.set_xlabel('Score')

for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container,size=13,fmt='%.2f', color = '#17191a', padding=5)
```

[image]

Comment: read the xlim with `xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()`, then set it again with `plt.xlim(xmin-0.5, xmax+0.5)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang that doesn't seem to work... unless I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: `0.5` is a bit small in this case.  But using `ax.margins(x=0.2)` is easier and more robust. (Here`0.2` means 20% whitespace added left and right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohanC 's comment: `ax.margins(x=0.2)` did the trick!